# Sequelize relations foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a post route that is using the sequelize create method to add an event to the database. I have defined the tables for user and event as such:

Events

```
    const Events = sequelize.define('Events', {
        Event_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
          },
          name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
          },
          month: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
          },
          day:{
            type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
          },
          year: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
          },
          important:{
              type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
              allowNull: false,
              defaultValue: false
          },
          description:{
              type: DataTypes.STRING,
              allowNull: true
          }
    });
    return Events;
}
```

User

```
    const User = sequelize.define('Users', {
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
          },
          name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
          },
          email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
          },
          password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
          }
    }, {});
    User.associate = function(models){
      User.hasMany(models.Events, {as: 'user'})
    }
    return User;
}
```

The post route seems to run correctly with the exception on sequelize not being able to attach the user Id to the event that is created do to

> "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`planitdb`.`events`, CONSTRAINT `events_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`UserUserId`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)"

I am not sure I understand exactly why this is happening. I am thinking I need to define the relation in the Events table as well?  If that is the case, I am not sure I understand what type of relationship the Events table has with the User table. Or is the relationship a single event to a single user?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your events object does not contain a mapping for user_id. This object needs to include a user_id field and this needs to be populated prior to attempting to insert a record to the events table.

EDIT - including sequelize relations solution:

Instead of this:

```
const Events = sequelize.define('Events', {...});
User.associate = function(models){
  User.hasMany(models.Events, {as: 'user'})
}
```

Try:

```
const Events = sequelize.define('Events', {...});
const User = sequelize.define('User', {...});
User.hasMany(Events, {as: 'user'});
```

or:

```
const Events = sequelize.define('Events', {});
const User = sequelize.define('User', {...});
Events.belongsTo(User,{
    foreignKey: 'user_id',
    constraints: false,
    as: 'user'
});
```

Comment: I was under the impression that I would do this trough sequelize relations but for this it should work the way that you described.

Comment: Like anything, there are many ways to accomplish the same outcome. You could (and likely should) use sequelize relations to accomplish this. I didn't see the hasMany relation at the end. You should try using belongsTo on the events entity. Either belongsTo, or manually defining the field as I mentioned should get you there.